# How do I fix this memory leak while using Chromium Embedded?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

The GuiDemo code for Chromium Embedded (https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) is leaking few bytes of memory. Not much but it is VERY annoying to get that message from FastMM every time you stop the app. I guess the leak is in the Chromium Interface.
The unit has a Initialization section:

```
INITIALIZATION
 CefCache := 'cache';
 CefRegisterCustomSchemes := CefOnRegisterCustomSchemes;
 CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory('dcef', '', True, TFileScheme);
```

---

The log is this:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x1674, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
40455E 
4050A7 
409C1D 
405622 
4050DC 
4F0D7A 
406598 
406604 
40A6C3 
4F0E28 
764CEE1C [BaseThreadInitThunk]

The block is currently used for an object of class: main$174$ActRec
The allocation number is: 323

--------------------------------2014/10/5 17:11:33--------------------------------
This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):
13 - 20 bytes: main$174$ActRec x 1
```

The thing is that I have no clue who main$174$ActRec is.
The unit that hosts the demo is called indeed 'main.pas'. But there is no other var called 'main'.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  It's a perfectly reasonable question, albeit with some lack of understanding of what's going on.  It is not one bit strange for singletons to leak a little bit of memory and not have a cleanup function for it.

Comment: The SO community tends to downvote questions which members are unable to answer, because they think the error could only be in the question. The SO community also tends to downvote questions which members are able to answer, because they think the asker shows no effort to solve the problem by her/himself. This is especially true for Delphi questions.

Answer (score 5):

`main$174$ActRec` is associated with the interface used to support an anonymous method. So that should give you a clue as how to look for the leak.

If you included an exception logging suite like madExcept, EurekaLog of JCL, you'd get a meaningful stack trace from FastMM. That also would help you find where the leak originates.

Once you can find what has been leaked then it ought to be possible to find a way to register it as an expected leak. However, if you can identify what has been leaked then I'd suggest trying to find a way not to leak it.

I can't help you identify the leak further because you didn't give any more information. There are many demos for this project and I don't know which one you are running.

Comment: Seems to be the GUIClient demo.

Comment: It is the GUI Client demo indeed.

Comment: Well, you know what to look for now

Comment: @Altar are you looking for more? Bear in mind that I still don't know what code you are running because I don't know which version of the demo you use or which version of Delphi you use. You really should get decent stack trace and identify the anon method.

Comment: Hi David - The demo I am using is called 'guiclient'. It is the latest version (which I think is May 2012) that I downloaded from their web site few days ago. I use Delphi XE. I will get a stack trace as you said.

Comment: I found no memory leak when I ran, but then I didn't use XE since I didn't know which version you were using. Surely you can find the anon method in that unit.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that the memory block **holds** an instance of a `main$174$ActRec` class, not that the memory was allocated by the `main$174$ActRec` class.  Somewhere in your app, `ActRec.Create()` is being called, but `ActRec.Destroy()` was not called.  Since you do not know the exact memory address of the object being leaked, or at least the memory address of the variable that points at the object,  you cannot register it by address.  However, the full version of FastMM has an overloaded `RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` function that accepts a class type and count as input.  That allows you to tell FastMM how many instances of the class type are allowed to be leaked before FastMM starts reporting them as leaks. Of course, that means you need access to the class type.  If it is something internal to Chromium, you may be out of luck.

Comment: The $ symbol makes this an "unspeakable" name. Only the compiler can instantiate this thing.